# How can I host a c# control in a win32 app?

Tags: c#, winapi, controls, host

I've developed a c# control, and I can reuse this in other c# apps and that works really well.

However I want to host this control in a Win32 c++ app, is there a way to do this?

I was wondering if it would work with managed c++, however I can't quite figure out if this is possible.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Cheers
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Com Interop Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb419144.aspx) to solve this.

This is how I do it:
I create my control in C#
When I want to expose this control to another Win32 app, I expose this control via com.
I create a new project using this com interop toolkit, create a new control, and put my C# version of my usercontrol on this new control.
Then, you should have a com-exposable version of that control.  At least, that's in short how i do it.

Comment: ah perhaps I should have been more specific, I need to display the control in a Wn32 c++ app.

Comment: Yes, that's what he meant.  You'll need to provide an ActiveX control host in your C++ code.  ATL's CAxWindow or MFC's COleControlContainer for example.  Don't write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks, no no I don't want to write one I want to take advantage of existing technologies. Do you have link to an example of this?